# How many "near-Fermat triples" are there?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Is the following statement true?

> **Claim**
>
> For every $n\in \mathbb N$, there is a constant $d$ such that there
>   are infinitely many triples $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$ with
>
> $$ | a^n + b^n - c^n | \le d $$

For $n=2$, we can take $d=0$ and use the Pythagorean triples. For $n>2$, there are no triples with $d=0$ (Fermat's last theorem).

Comment: My intuition says it should be true for small $n$ because there are enough degrees of freedom. But probabilistically it looks quite bleak for large $n$.

Comment: Related question recently asked on MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214422/fermats-last-theorem-pm-k and in particular note  math.harvard.edu/~elkies/ferm.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fermat's Last Theorem near misses?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526330/fermats-last-theorem-near-misses)

Comment: @Stefan4024 That post doesn't seem to answer this specific question with $|\cdot |\le d$