# Fermat's Last Theorem: arbitrarily near-integer solutions

Tags: number-theory

Fermat's Last Theorem states that there exist no positive integers $x, y, z$ such that $x^n + y^n = z^n$, for integer $n > 2$.

If we allow for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, it is obvious that there are infinitely many solutions (take arbitrary $x, y$ and choose $z = \sqrt[n]{x^n + y^n}$).

However, do there always exist solutions with arbitrarily near-integer values? In other words, for each integer $n>2$ and real number $\varepsilon > 0$, we want to find $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$ so that:

- $|x-x'| < \varepsilon, |y-y'| < \varepsilon, |z-z'| < \varepsilon$ with $ x', y', z' \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$
- $x^n + y^n = z^n$

Comment: Yes, that's why I specified $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ (edit: never mind, the comment I replied to got deleted)

Comment: @DietrichBurde In many definitions, naturals are the positive integers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I've edited the question to remove the ambiguity, and also removed the last line to stick to the question.

Comment: If you're including zero in your definition of natural numbers, then there exists a solution to Fermat's last theorem @Marcel

Comment: Perhaps also interesting is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526330/fermats-last-theorem-near-misses?rq=1). But here only the quotient $(x^3+y^3)/z^3$ goes to $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess its true. Let me try a proof: Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 3$ and given $\varepsilon>0$. Pick $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y=1$. Then set
$$z=(x^n+1)^\frac{1}{n}.$$
If we show
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty,x\in\mathbb{N}}|(x^n+1)^\frac{1}{n}-x|=0.$$
we can choose $x$ to be big enough, such that
$$|z-x|=|(x^n+1)^\frac{1}{n}-(x^n)^\frac{1}{n}|<\varepsilon.$$
Since $x\in\mathbb{N}$ the result follows.
Let us take a look at the limit: The mean value theorem applied to $t\mapsto t^\frac{1}{n}$ yields a $\xi\in[x^n,x^n+1]$ such that
$$|(x^n+1)^\frac{1}{n}-(x^n)^\frac{1}{n}| =  \frac{1}{n}(\xi)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(x^n+1-x^n).$$
Since the exponent $\frac{1}{n}-1$ is negativ, we get
$$|(x^n+1)^\frac{1}{n}-(x^n)^\frac{1}{n}|\leq\frac{1}{n}(x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$$
Again with $\frac{1}{n}-1$ being negative, the result follows.

Comment: Did you mean for the right-hand side of the inequality to be $\frac{1}{n} (x^n)^{\frac{1}{n} - 1}$?

Comment: @ Marcel: You are correct, since $\frac{1}{n}-1$ is negativ the biggest point of the derivative of $t\mapsto t^\frac{1}{n}$ in the intervall $[x^n,x^n+1]$ is actually $x^n$. I will correct it in an edit.